# How to reverse an import function?

Tags: windows, functions, windows-10

I'm reversing windows `.sys` file and an import function `RtlLookupEntryHashTable` appears in my target functions. I want to know the pseudocode of it. How to achieve this?

```
.text:00000001C00218C2                 call    cs:wcsnlen
.text:00000001C00218C9                 nop     dword ptr [rax+rax+00h]
.text:00000001C00218CE                 mov     rdx, r15
.text:00000001C00218D1                 mov     ecx, ebx
.text:00000001C00218D3                 lea     r8d, [rax+rax]
.text:00000001C00218D7                 call    RtlCompute37Hash
.text:00000001C00218DC                 bts     eax, 1Fh
.text:00000001C00218E0                 lea     r8, [rsp+0B8h+Context] ; Context
.text:00000001C00218E5                 xorps   xmm0, xmm0
.text:00000001C00218E8                 mov     edx, eax        ; Signature
.text:00000001C00218EA                 lea     rcx, stru_1C0077988 ; HashTable
.text:00000001C00218F1                 mov     ebx, eax
.text:00000001C00218F3                 movdqu  xmmword ptr [rsp+0B8h+Context.ChainHead], xmm0
.text:00000001C00218F9                 call    cs:RtlLookupEntryHashTable
.text:00000001C0021900                 nop     dword ptr [rax+rax+00h]
```

When I double clicked it, I got this

```
.idata:00000001C007E378                                         ; sub_1C0014BCC+107↑p ...
.idata:00000001C007E380 ; PRTL_DYNAMIC_HASH_TABLE_ENTRY __stdcall RtlLookupEntryHashTable(PRTL_DYNAMIC_HASH_TABLE HashTable, ULONG_PTR Signature, PRTL_DYNAMIC_HASH_TABLE_CONTEXT Context)
.idata:00000001C007E380                 extrn RtlLookupEntryHashTable:qword
.idata:00000001C007E380                                         ; CODE XREF: KfdAleRemoveFlowContextTable+102↑p
.idata:00000001C007E380                                         ; KfdAleAcquireEndpointContextFromFlow+92↑p ...
.idata:00000001C007E388 ; BOOLEAN __stdcall KeTestSpinLock(PKSPIN_LOCK SpinLock)
.idata:00000001C007E388                 extrn KeTestSpinLock:qword
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. It's not quite clear what you want. What's your question? If you want to see pseudo-code for a function imported from elsewhere, you'll have to open that _elsewhere_ location (in this case likely `ntoskrnl.exe`) and find the function there and throw a decompiler at that.

Comment: Like 0xC0000022L said, it's a function from `ntoskrnl.exe` that your `.sys` file imported and used. If you just want to know that that function does, you can search on Google. If you want to know the pseudo-code, you can decompile `ntoskrnl.exe` or you can view the (clone) source code of that function from ReactOS project

Comment: I found it in the import finally. Thx